# Jewelry evaluation certificate for Canada PR

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

Do I need jewelry evaluation certificate for silver jewelry and silverware when I am landing canada for the first time as new immigrant?

Comment: What purpose would that serve?

Comment: Also, migration questions should be posted on expatriates.stackexchange.com/ Not sure this would be on topic there, though.

Answer (score 2):

The website of the [Goverment of Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/prepare-life-canada/border-entry/bringing-goods.html) states:

> **Bringing goods to Canada**
> When you move to Canada from another country, you may bring your personal and household goods with you without paying duty. You’ll have to pay duty on any item you bring that hasn’t been used.
>
> You don’t have to pay duty on  . . . jewellery

> **Jewellery or precious ornaments**
> Officers may ask you questions about your jewellery or precious ornaments during your customs interview. Make sure you describe these items on your list of goods. To avoid delays at customs when you enter Canada:
>
> - use the wording from your insurance policy or jeweler’s appraisal on your list of goods
> - include photographs of the items
> - know how much you paid for the items or have a receipt showing how much you paid
> - you don’t need to pay duty or tax on family heirlooms

Comment: Thanks but my major doubt is do we need evaluation certificate for silverware pooja items??iam planning to take 500 gms of pooja silver Items

Comment: This section says "Jewellery or **precious ornaments**".

Comment: Okie Thank you..I missed that...so I have to take evaluation certificate for silver ornaments as well...Thanks for ur help